# Symbolic Link says it is pointing to correct folder but goes to parent in FileZilla

Tags: symbolic-link

I used the following to create a symbolic link

`ln -s /var/www/example.com/target/public_html faker`

When I use `readfile faker` it shows the correct link but when I navigate through FileZilla it take me to `/var/www/example.com/target/` and not `public_html`

My web app is not going to the correct folder either. Am I doing something wrong?

Okay more information; noticed that it is creating a self referential symbolic `public_html` link in `/var/www/example.com/target/public_html`. Actually - this only happens when I try to change the target link by force (-f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working as follows, navigated to `/var/www/example.com/target/public_html` folder then issued following: `ln -s /var/www/example.com/target/public_html faker`. Could be that I wasn't in the correct folder.